# Changing primary_key in django model

Tags: python, mysql, django

previously I didn't have **id** in **Server** class and primary_key was in **name**, but I wanted to allow users to create multiple **Servers** with the same name so I decided to create **id** as a primary_key in **Server** model.

models.py

```py
class Server(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, default=404)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        User, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    users = models.ManyToManyField(
        User, 
        default=owner, 
        related_name='server_users',
    )
```

When i'm trying to migrate changes I get error **django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1068, 'Multiple primary key defined')**

You can reproduce it from [github repo](https://github.com/n3rsti/ToDoChat) by changing **Server** model like above: adding id with primary_key = True and removing primary_key from **name**

Comment: You probably already made a `Server` model and first migrated *before* adding a new one? Based on the history, previously the `name` was the primary key.

Comment: Exactly, previous primary_key was name, but I don't know how to fix it. Delete and re-create model? I also tried to do it on new database without any users and models, but after changing primary key to i get error about multiple pk

Comment: @KrzysztofWiucki: if you do not have any (important) data yet, I think that is the easiest. I think Django has no migration tooling for a changing primary key.

Comment: It worked, thanks! I have one more question, but I think it's simple so I don't want to create a new thread for it. In [views.py](https://github.com/n3rsti/ToDoChat/blob/master/todochat/app/views.py) I have form_validation function **form_valid()**. I wanted to add id so I tried `form.instance.id = create_id(form.cleaned_data.get('name'))`, but it's not working. (maybe it's to early to get data, idk) is there any other way to add **id** to **Server** model basing on form data?